# ¿Cómo obtener datos de una ventana pop-up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Estoy tratando de hacer click() en el elemento de "muestra rapida" del siguiente link : https://www.shein.com/Tops-c-1766.html?icn=tops&ici=www_tab01navbar04menu08&page=1

mi idea es hacerle click para luego elegir la cantidad de productos en el input que abre la ventana emergente luego de hacerle `click()`.

Código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.shein.com/Tops-c-1766.html?icn=tops&ici=www_tab01navbar04menu08&page=1')
page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html.parser")
articles = [i for i in page.find_all(class_="c-goodsli")]

for indice in range(1,len(articles)+1):
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div['+str(indice)+']/div[4]/div[1]/button[1]').click()
    except:
        boton=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div['+str(indice)+']/div[4]/div[1]/button[1]')
        print(boton.get_attribute('data-id'))
```

Comentarios:

En `articles` saco la cantidad de productos de la página. 
En el loop, lo que trato de hacer es clickear en el item.. y en la excepción muestro el id del producto, sólo para chequear que efectivamente esta tomando bien el elemento, pero por alguna razón no hace `click()`.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿La ventana emergente llega a aparecer? Es decir, ¿el click sobre el quick view es efectivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En estos casos, lo primero que deberías considerar es eliminar el `try-except` o imprimir la excepción para saber por qué falla. En mi caso es un problema muy típico:

> ```
> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
>     Element <button class="she-btn-white-opacity she-btn-s quickv-btn j-gds-li-qvbtn">
>         could not be scrolled into view
> ```

Eso nos indica que el elemento no está disponible para ser mostrado en la ViewPort , el área visible para el usuario en la página.

Ten en cuenta que el botón está oculto hasta el momento de posicionarse encima del articulo correspondiente. Además, hay otro botón, con la misma clase, que se muestra cuando se hace click en el primero mostrando que se está cargando el modal.

Seguramente existan otras formas de lidiar con esto, pero la siguiente es la más intuitiva, simplemente emulamos lo que un "humano" haría:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.shein.com/Tops-c-1766.html?icn=tops&ici=www_tab01navbar04menu08&page=1')
articulos = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("c-goodsli")

div = browser.find_element_by_class_name("config-wrap")
for articulo in articulos:
    ActionChains(browser).click(div).perform()
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(articulo).perform()
    boton = WebDriverWait(articulo, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//button[contains(text(), 'QUICK VIEW')]"))
    )
    boton.click()

    WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "modal-content"))
        )

    browser.implicitly_wait(10) # Hacer lo que sea en el modal
```

He eliminado BeautifulSoup, se puede hacer lo mismo con Selenium sin necesidad de otra librería.

- `ActionChains(browser).click(div).perform()` solo sirve para hacer click fuera de los modales (tanto los que buscas como el que aparece a veces de bienvenida) y así cerrarlos.
- `ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(articulo).perform()` emular el posicionamiento del cursor encima de cada artículo, lo cual hace visible el botón.
- `boton = WebDriverWait(articulo, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable....)` nos retorna el botón una vez que este sea visible y permita hacer click en él.

El código está probado con GeckoDriver (Firefox) pero no debería dar problemas con ChromeDriver.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. fue de mucha utilidad

Comment: De nada Lucas, iba a responder a tu comentario anterior cuando he visto que lo has eliminado ¿Te funciona ahora correctamente? La página en si es bastante "pesada", si te salta algún timeout como el que comentabas puedes probar aumentando el tiempo de espera (`WebDriverWait(articulo, 10)` -> `WebDriverWait(articulo, 30)` por ejemplo). No se si se me habrá pasado algo, el scraping de las páginas con tanto contenido dinámico es a veces complejo, que si modal con ofertas, con el aviso de cookies... que se colocan delante de lo que quieres... muchas veces es cuestión de ensayo-error... Un saludo.

Comment: Si, es que la linea de ´EC.visibility_of_element_located´, la tuve que dejar comentada, porque me tira un TimeoutException, y no me dice nada, solo" Message : "  .